# Deny entry using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a page `home.php` where you can only access by loging in and inside this page you can download files. What I am trying to do is that if you put in your browser: `www.domain.com/home.php/file.pdf` and enter, it does not download the file. I mean, that you can only download the file by clicking on the link in `home.php`.

I have tried this code, but when I click the link, it sends me Error: Forbidden.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^https://www.domanin.com/home.php" local_ref=1
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from env=local_ref
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: checking referers is **NOT** secure. referer is beyond easy to forge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer ^https?://www.domanin.com/home.php/.+\.pdf local_ref=1

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All
Deny from env=local_ref
```

This will forbid the request for 
- https://www.domanin.com/home.php/file.pdf (referer).

Comment: Hi @starkeen, thank you for your answer. The problem is that the name of the file will depend on the person who uploads the file. The name will hardly ever be "file".